# How to break a csv column to several different columns based on words?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a data set in a csv file that is in one column, but each row in the column contains data that could be column data with a value. I'm not sure how to parse the data so that the data is broken up by what would be the column data and the related value. The data looks something like this:

**Column A,row1:**

```
Name:Jane Doe 
ID:123456  
Company: J.Crew  
Allergies: None  
Age:25  
Job Title: Analyst
```

**Column A, row2:**

```
Name: John Doe  
ID: 654321  
Company:Banana Republic  
Allergies: peanuts   
Age:32  
Job Title:Manager
```

There are a hundred rows similar to these and I want it turn the data into a Name column, ID column, Company column, Age column, Job title column. I want to remove allergies item.

Example CSV file:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include actual sample data from the file (we don't need the whole thing, and you can change the data to protect the innocent).

Comment: There are no commas in the rows?  If not, then it's not a CSV.  Can you add the first few rows of the actual file to your question?

Comment: I attached a picture of a sample of what the csv file would look like.

Answer (score 0):

I'll look up some example code later but here is the logic:

1. Create a string to hold the new data (myNewData)
2. Open the file
3. Read the file line by line
4. Split the line by a colon
5. Identify the first word in the line (the first part of the split)
6. If the first word *is not* "Name:" and *is not* allergies, then add a comma and the value (second part of the split from 4, with a trim of the whitespace). Append this to myNewData.
7. If the first word *is* allergies, then discard and start the next loop
8. If the first word *is* "Name:", then add a newline ('\n') and the value.
9. When the process completes, write myNewData to a new file.

Example code below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def decider(line):    
    try:
        first_part, second_part = lines.split(':')
        if first_part not in ('Name', 'Allergies'):
            return ',' + second_part.strip()
        elif first_part == 'Name':
            return '\n' + second_part.strip()
        else:
            return ''
    except:
        return ''

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    myNewData = 'Name,ID,Company,Age,Job'
    for lines in f.readlines():
        myNewData += decider(lines)
    # print(myNewData)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as fo:
        fo.write(myNewData)
```

and you have a nice, new csv.

The output will look like:

Name,ID,Company,Age,Job
Jane Doe,123456,J.Crew,25,Analyst
John Doe,654321,Banana Republic,32,Manager

Comment: I need the output to be in columns. So you have a column of names with rows going down with the different names.

Comment: That is what the above output will give you.

Comment: If you mean that you want the data to be separated by spaces rather than commas, then you change the `return ',' + second_part.strip()` line to `return '\t' + second_part.strip()` - you would probably also want to think about enclosing the columns in quote marks, depending on what you planned to with it afterwards (`\t` is the tab character)

Comment: Thanks for the help! If I had some free form line text after Job Title with no starting keyword, is there an easy way to include that in a column after Job Title?

Comment: Yes, with a bit of rejigging. Hopefully you're saying the order is Job Title: Job Code -> newline -> free text (person description, comments etc.) which may or may not include newlines -> restart structured processing with Name:, where no line in the free text starts with the words "Name:"!